# Trigger multiple azure devops Pipelines in Parallel to create VM's on Azure using same Terraform module

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have terraform Module for example to create a VM on Azure and it works when I trigger the Pipeline.

But When I trigger the Pipeline twice it fails to create two VM's. How do I manipulate terraform State file ? Only way I can think of is two run multiple pipeline in different agents, does that work ?

Comment: If each VM is managed independently then each should have its own state file.

Comment: Terraform is intended to keep track of created resources and update them when the definition changes, rather than one-off, fire-and-forget script. You could move/delete the state file to make terraform "forget" about created resources - but then it'll loose track of them. Alternatively, consider using [count](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/count.html) or [for_each](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html) arguments - i.e. the pipeline might have a parameter that defines total number of required VMs.

Comment: Does Moving/deleting state file is a best practice ? Started to think of Count and for each but we don't have the requirement everytime to create 2 to 3 instances at a time. Don't we have any other alternatives ? I have searched for the answer but with no luck

Answer (score 0):

What we have done is create terraform "common" modules (basically a subdirectory with tf files), which we source into a terraform environment multiple times with different parameters.

These we usually put into a list with a loop.

In your environments terraform:

```
locals {
  azure_vms = [
    { name = "vm1", size = "Standard_B2s" },
    { name = "vm2", size = "Standard_B4s" }
  ]
}

module "my_azure_vm" {
  source   = "./common/my_azure_vm"
  for_each = { for vm in local.azure_vms : vm.name => vm }
  size = each.value.size
  name = each.value.name
}
```

In common my_azure_vm, you can define inputs for size and name, then use those to create the VM's with your standard parameters.